# Do native promises in JavaScript (ES6) have a default onFulfilled handler?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I'm reviewing the implementation of promises in ES6 and am wondering about the behavior in the following example. In this example, I don't register handlers with the then() method right away. Doing so (in Chrome 43) logs an error in the console when the promise is rejected, though the handler still executes.

My assumption is that I get the error because the promise is rejected before I've attached the handler (due to the setTimeout). But by that logic, shouldn't Chrome also log an error when the promise is determined to be resolved? What's going on here?

```js
var par = document.querySelector('p');

var P = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var v = Math.random();
    if(v < 0.5){resolve(v)}
    else{reject(v)}
});


//wait to attach handlers
setTimeout(function(){
    var n = P.then(
        function(v){
            par.innerHTML = "Good, "+v+" is less than 0.5.";
        },
        function(v){
            par.innerHTML = "Uh oh, "+v+" is greater than or equal to 0.5.";
        }
    )
},1000);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Comment: Chrome's 'native' promises behave incorrectly

Comment: What do you mean by "shouldn't Chrome also throw an error when the promise is determined to be resolved?"

Comment: @JaromandaX Care to expand on that? While this behavior isn't in the spec, it's very common and I'm not sure I'd classify it as "incorrect".

Comment: @loganfsmyth - every Promise library I've ever used that (at least purports to) conforms to Promise/A+ spec does not require an immediate .catch() in order to avoid uncaught exceptions if the promise is rejected before any then method is called. The fact that a resolve before then works fine, there should be no difference for a reject in this respect

Comment: @JaromandaX I agree, but this doesn't throw an uncaught exception, it just prints a message. The behavior of the promise itself still conforms normally, attaching a rejection handler afterward works fine.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - sorry, the error I see in chrome is "unhandled exception" - but this only occurs if you have the console open at the time, there's no indication otherwise if the console isn't open, so yes, absolutely no impact. And I have to take back what I said about no other Promise doing this. Firefox also does this, just not immediately.

Comment: Nothing is misbehaving. This is intended behavior and is currently being standardized.

Comment: No, there is no "`unhandled fulfillment`" thing, because that would be expected to log every single promise chain. It's not an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You ran into unhandled rejection detection

This is basically Chrome having your back. In realistic promise usage you *almost never* attach rejection handlers asynchronously. Rejections are rare (like exceptions) and you never want to leave a promise "hanging" with no error handler if it might reject.

Chrome is letting you know that you have a rejection that you did not attach a handler for synchronously *. This is in order for rejections to net get swallowed in cases like:

```
Promise.resolve().then(function(){
    var obj = JSON.prase("{}"); // note the typo
    console.log(obj);
});
```

If Chrome didn't do this and this was a nested chain - you'd get a very hard to debug error. The fact Chrome does this is a really good thing and it's currently being standardized so all browsers do this.

The moral of the story is:

#### Always attach rejection handlers synchronously.

There is seldom reason not to do so.

(*) The actual algorithm is within a microtask but let's ignore that.

Here is [the specification](https://github.com/domenic/unhandled-rejections-browser-spec) if you're curious: https://github.com/domenic/unhandled-rejections-browser-spec

Here is the spec for Node/io.js: https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2

Answer (score 1):

It's just a failsafe for code that might not handle the error for developer convenience.  It shouldn't effect other code, and is only visible in the console and debugger.  If an error is thrown in synchronous code, and not caught, the default behavior is for that error to be logged to the console.  With promises, thrown errors are caught and handled by rejecting the promise.  Since the JS engine can't easily know whether a rejected promise will be handled in the future, if a promise is rejected, and there is no handler at the time that it is rejected, most browsers will log a message to the console.

If you want to prevent that, you can do similar code to what you would do with synchronous code.  Where you would have a `try`/`catch` in synchronous code, you would use a no-op `.catch()` handler for promises.

```js
var par = document.querySelector('p');

var P = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var v = Math.random();
    if(v < 0.5){resolve(v)}
    else{reject(v)}
});
P.catch(function(reason){
    // noop
});

//wait to attach handlers
setTimeout(function(){
    var n = P.then(
        function(v){
            par.innerHTML = "Good, "+v+" is less than 0.5.";
        },
        function(v){
            par.innerHTML = "Uh oh, "+v+" is greater than or equal to 0.5.";
        }
    )
},1000);
```

```html
<p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reworking your code to use promises consistently. This is one of those cases where interop between promises and callbacks can cause trouble. Promises are meant to be chained, if you find that you have a good reason to chain them after long periods of time, you should consider if you can rework your code to synchronously set up the chain.

In this case for example, you need to flip that `setTimeout` around:

```
function delay(ms){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
}

var par = document.querySelector('p');

var P = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var v = Math.random();
    if(v < 0.5){resolve(v)}
    else{reject(v)}
});

P.then(
    function(result){
        return delay(1000).then(function(){ return result; });
    },
    function(err){
        return delay(1000).then(function(){ throw err; });
    }
).then(
    function(v){
        par.innerHTML = "Good, "+v+" is less than 0.5.";
    },
    function(v){
        par.innerHTML = "Uh oh, "+v+" is greater than or equal to 0.5.";
    }
)
```